# SocketIO is 20 seconds late

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, socket.io

I'm trying to connect my backend (python, flask) and frontend (react) with sockets, but the every time the sockets are around 20 seconds late.

backend:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
CORS(app)

socketio.emit('message', 'test')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

frontend:

```
const App = () => {

    const [message, setMessage] = useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        const socket = io('http://localhost:5000')
        socket.on("message", data => {
            setMessage(data)
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {message}
        </div>
    )
}
```

So the word `test` appears 20 seconds after loading the page. Why? Is it possible to do it faster?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with phyton, however try inspecting your network tab in chrome devtools. Filter by WS and doubleclick on the socket connection and see when you receive the event.

Comment: @sharpness When I try to do that my browser crashes